# Delete some <div> on loading webpage

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

Most website display ads. These are usually placed in

```
<div class="googlead">//code here</div>
```

I went to "Inspect Element" in chrome and deleted the div and the webpage looked beautiful.

So is there some script out there wherein

```
// PESUDOCODE
IF website url contains stackoverflow keyword THEN
    delete this <div> having this class="googlead"
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these scripts are already written for you in the form of browser plugins, like Adblock Plus. http://adblockplus.org/

If you're curious, you can see the source code for their various plugins here: https://github.com/adblockplus

Comment: But what if I want to block specific user defined <div> in frequently used site like stackoverflow and not mess with banking websites?

Comment: Then you can just modify the filter settings for the Adblock Plus plugin. See here: http://adblockplus.org/en/filters

Comment: So edit the code of plugin adblock and make your own plugin that scans for keywords, if the url contains stackoverflow, then delete this div?